# Is it possible to run a stored procedure against every database and not use sp_MSforeachdb?

Tags: sql-server

I have multiple databases. They all have a `tablea`. I have a stored procedure that takes data from `tablea` and inserts it into a central table - `central.dbo.consol`.

I'd like to run my sp against all database without making it a system stored procedure and without using `sp_MSforeachdb`.

Is there a way to do that without adding the stored procedure to every DB?

I'd like to be able to dynamically run the stored procedure against all databases so as databases are added or removed - I don't have to do anything.

Thanks. Only methods I know are using `sp_MSforeachdb` or making the stored procedure a system stored procedure.

Modified for SO - example only - may have syntax issues;

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_updateee] 
AS

MERGE INTO dw.All_Socks WITH (holdlock) L
USING (
SELECT ca.*
FROM   (VALUES('fa', 
               'be')) DefaultValues([falcon], [beaver])
       CROSS APPLY (

                   SELECT 
                          falcon,
                          beaver,
                          raddate,
                          sessionid, 
                          rust
                    FROM   "Instance" u
                    WHERE  
                        raddate >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE())
                        ) ca)  ca(falcon, beaver, raddate, sessionid, rust),
                    ON L.sessionid = ca.sessionid AND L.rust = ca.rust
                    WHEN NOT matched THEN
                      INSERT
                      VALUES (
                      falcon,
                      beaver,
                      raddate,
                      sessionid,
                      rust
```

Comment: Would using SELECT * FROM SYS.DATABASES make it a system stored procedure?

Comment: Why you don't want to use `sp_MSforeachdb`? Despite his name this proc doesn't require to have a SP to call, but simply execute a T-SQL command.

Comment: Build your own dynamic SQL statement, that isn't `sp_MSforeachdb`? There are plenty of alternatives out there. Write your procedure, whatever that is, so that *it* automatically goes through the databases, rather than having multiple instances of the *same* SP in every database.

Comment: @RossBush No it would not.

Comment: @Larnu I'm not sure which methodology to use or what you're specifically saying.

Comment: *"I'm not sure which methodology to use"* well that's the first step. Do you want to loop? Do you want to create one giant dynamic statement? Do those statements need to be in their own scopes? We have no details of what you are actually trying to achieve here, just a vague problem and that you *don't* want to use `sp_MSforeachdb`. Why specifically don't you want to use it? Are you against *other* solutions? Could your SP use `sp_MSforeachdb` or something like [`sp_ineachdb`](//www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5694/execute-a-command-in-the-context-of-each-database-in-sql-server-part-2)

Comment: @Larnu, so you're saying select from, `SYS.DATABASES` and loop through results? The problem I am trying to solve is in OP. Basically - I have an SP that takes data from one table to another and I wanna run the sp against all databases.

Comment: Looping through `sys.databases` would be one option, yes. Can you post the definition of the procedure in the question?

Comment: @Larnu I don't see a cohesive point you're trying to make. Sorry, I re read your comments twice, but I just don't get it. If you're overall point is "try a bunch of stuff" - please just clearly say because I sure am not following. The deinition? It just takes data from one and merges into a table. Thanks.

Comment: Put the definition of the procedure in the question. *Then* we can demonstrate examples. The reason you are getting vague ideas is because we only have a vague idea of the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: The problem to solve is - Run an SP in one database against all other databases without the SP being present in them. Does that clear it up?

Comment: @Larnu I don't know if it helps but I put what the SP does in OP.

Comment: `WHERE AND`? `, ON`? Are we missing something? That definition isn't valid. Why use a `MERGE` when you only `INSERT`?

Comment: No, not missing anything. There is a note `Modified for SO - example only - may have syntax issues;`. I just used a merged so I could use when not matched. It was an early draft. I can do an insert. `on` is part of the merge.

Comment: @RobertoFerraris I think a quick search for sp_MSforeachdb will yield a bunch of reasons.

Comment: @Stuckat1337 I don't follow? I was asking if I answered their question. Did I not answer it? I explained the problem and posted the code in OP. Did I misread what they wanted? Did you see the comment below it"@Larnu I don't know if it helps but I put what the SP does in OP" ? I'm not following what you're saying? I think I answered them.

Comment: @Stuckat1337 I don't see it, but thank you for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

you can to use dynamic query and sp_MSforeachdb

I use dynamic query

this code ,you can create dynamic query  include check exists sp and execute

```
declare @Query nvarchar(max)=''
select @Query=@Query+' use ' +name +' if (exists (
SELECT  *  FROM    sys.objects  WHERE   object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''FillToData'')
AND type IN ( N''P'', N''PC'' )))
begin

insert into [central].[dbo].[consol] ([Name]
      ,[Family]
      ,[Grade])  exec FillToData 
end   
      ' from sys.databases
      where name not in ('master','msdb','tempdb','model')
      print( @Query)
```

The code below contains the create databases, create table and create proc FillToData

```
 create database central
 go
 USE [central]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[consol](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL, [Family] [nvarchar](50) NULL, [Grade] [int] NULL)
go
 create database mydatabasenew
 go
  USE [mydatabasenew]
GO
create proc FillToData
as
select 'test1' as Name,'tef1' as Family,17 as n
union all

select 'test2' as Name,'tef2' as Family,11 as n
union all
select 'test3' as Name,'tef3' as Family,13 as n

go
 create database mydatabasenew2
 go
  USE [mydatabasenew2]
GO
create proc FillToData
as
select 'test4' as Name,'tef54' as Family,10 as n
union all

select 'test6' as Name,'tef55' as Family,14 as n
union all
select 'test9' as Name,'tef56' as Family,20 as n
```

Comment: I don't understand this solution. My table and SP already exist. I simply want to run my sp across all databases. `sp_MSforeachdb` is buggy and is known to skip.

Comment: You can to use sp_MSforeachdb and dynamic query to exec proc any database
I am using dynamic query
I put the example below example the code(create databases and tables ,...) @PopsicleBetweenMytoes

Comment: It's got too many extras making it hard to follow. Why do I need to create an already existing table?

Comment: @PopsicleBetweenMytoes Good grief fella, the extra creates are there so you can test this code exactly, independently, and not mess up your production system or have to change everything to match your real table names etc. and not mess up the intent in doing so (and then blame them). It's called a working demo.

Comment: @Stuckat1337 it's more than that. They are hard coding table names. The above is hard for me to follow because it deviates so far from what was asked. I didn't mean for you or anyone to take offense. It's just hard for me to follow when things are twisted past a certain degree beyond what was asked / counter to what was asked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want to do, the procedure itself must have the code that runs against different databases. You can't forward a procedure to another database anyway.
A proof of concept for what such a procedure could look like comes below:

```
ALTER procedure doStuffInDbs
AS
begin
    declare @name nvarchar(776)
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,   @tableExists BIT
    declare cr_x cursor read_only forward_only local static for
        select name
        --select *
        from sys.databases (NOLOCK)
        WHERE state_desc = 'ONLINE'
        and database_id > 4 -- skip master, tempdb, model, msdb...

    open cr_x

    while 1 = 1
    BEGIN
        FETCH NEXT FROM CR_X INTO @name
        IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0
            BREAK

        set @tableExists = 0
        SET @SQL = '
            USE ' + QUOTENAME(@name) + N'
            SELECT  @tableExists = 1
            FROM    sys.objects so
            WHERE   so.name = ''tablea'''
        EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
        ,   N'@tableExists BIT OUTPUT'
        ,   @tableExists = @tableExists  OUTPUT

        -- Jump out of table is missing...
        IF ISNULL(@tableExists, 0) <> 1
            CONTINUE

        PRINT 'PROCESSING: ' + @name
        SET @SQL = '
            USE ' + QUOTENAME(@name) + N'

            INSERT INTO central.dbo.consol (
                id, col1, col2, db
            )
            SELECT  id, col1, col2, DB_NAME()
            FROM    tablea
            '
        EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
            
    END
    CLOSE CR_X
    DEALLOCATE CR_X

end

GO

-- Test code
exec doStuffInDbs
```

What it does is fetch all databases in cursor, loop every one of them, checks if it has a table you need, and finally, perform some sort of operation on this table

Comment: Thank you. This is really clear. Going to test. I could make it a system sp in master and it could be forwarded that way, but I really don't want to do that. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't like the default values of my cross apply. Says columns don't exist but they aren't columns. They're strings. Trying to sort that out. Thanks again. Chipping away.